# How would I count the number of rows returned from an sql query using wordpress?

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I am currently using:

```
$dup_donor_count = count($wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM ".$table_name." WHERE Donor = '".$donor."'"));
```

which is giving me back '61', the total number of elements in the entire array, the array is an array of std objects, each of which is a row corresponding to my specified query, namely, where the Donor column is equal to 'Dave'.

There are 6 instances where this is true, how would I return this number (6) and not 61?

This is driving me nuts.

Comment: Are you sure,your $donor variable in query is getting value as "Dave"?

Comment: Yep, Ive checked the resulting array, there are loads of other columns like email, amount paid, etc etc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this here is salutation  i hope helped out

```
$wpdb->get_results("SELECT FROM ".$table_name." WHERE Donor = '".$donor."'");

echo $wpdb->num_rows;
```

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you are using `count` inside the `Select`?

```
$dup_donor_count = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ".$table_name." WHERE Donor = '".$donor."'");
```

Comment: I get "Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [COUNT(*)] => 6 ) ) 1" Almost there! Just need to now get the 6 into the count variable?

Comment: A late reply, but for anyone else who wonders as Peter in the above comment, you need to use `$wpdb->get_var($sql)` instead of `$wpdb->get_results()`